# Ruby on Rails or Node.js? Which is better for e-commerce websites?

Tags: ruby, node.js, e-commerce

I'm making an e-commerce website which deals with medicines, big number of them. I can't choose between Ruby on Rails and Node.js. Can someone tell me which would be more helpful?

I just need some opinions. 
Thanks

Comment: Node.js isn't a language.

Comment: @TheHippo Neither is Rails.

Comment: @destielstarship I was referring to: "I can't choose between ruby and node.js languages."

Comment: also consider: its not just about making the website. you will also have to integrate third party services: payment transactions, shipping, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a technology standpoint, both are very capable. It's going to be down to your preference and situation as to which one you choose.

However if this is a commercial project then I would say that the undoubted winner is going to be ruby. It's more mature than node and so enjoys better tooling, better "google-ability", and you are going to find it far easier to find staff that have experience developing and debugging it. These considerations are going to be far more important for most projects than a pure technical comparison.

Comment: Today, 3 Years later Do you still stand by what you said in your answer? Is Node a better option today than Ruby?

Answer (score 12):

You'll mostly get biased and opinionated answers to this question.

Both are very good choices, but you should pick what you're more familiar (or if you plan on learning, what you're more comfortable with). Also, you need to think about the platform you'll be deploying on: can you install additional software (like libraries) on it? Can you use `gem` (Ruby) or `npm`(Node.js) to install additional requirements you might need?

It's all very relative to *you*. They are both excellent tools.

---

**Note: Following answer is <del>probably</del>definitely opinionated.**

I'd say Rails, because it could (in my experience) be faster & easier to work with.

Performance-wise, I think node.js might be slightly better, but unless you're going to have a *lot* of traffic, it shouldn't matter.

Also, don't forget there's always [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) (MRI/CRuby) *or* [Puma](http://puma.io/) (JRuby, Rubinius), and combining those two with [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/), and you're on a horse! Well, on a puma or on a unicorn, technically... So, that would solve your performance issue, if one were to occur.

Also, Ruby (it is humanist, afterall) is a much more elegant language than JavaScript , although, you can get around its subjective uglyness[1] with [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/).

It comes down to preference, in the end. I love both, but I *slightly* prefer Ruby than JavaScript, and I also slightly prefer Rails over Node.js.

---

[1]: I don't find it ugly personally.

Comment: In my opinion claiming that "rails is faster" is a very bold statement.

Comment: @TheHippo I did no such thing. I explicitly said that Node would be better if performance is critical. I said: "...*faster & easier to work with*." which meant that development with Rails is faster than with Node. I can edit it if it's not clear enough.